# How to correctly replace 'localhost' with your own public IP in a mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, localhost

I'm looking to change `localhost` in my code to an IP that would work for users using the application i'm creating. Could someone help me out on what to type? I tried just putting my public IP but it returned `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

Any help on what to do would be fantastic. Also, if there's anything I need to do port-wise to make this happen, please include that, preferably with instructions.

Code:

```
else
{
   var constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=*****;password=*********";
   using (var con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
   {
      con.Open();

      var cmd0 = new MySqlCommand("select username from userinfo.users where username=@username");
      cmd0.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd0.Connection = con; // assign to connection
      cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", RUsernameTextBox.Text);
      bool userNameIsFree;

      using (var reader = cmd0.ExecuteReader())
      {
         userNameIsFree = !reader.HasRows;
      }

      if (!userNameIsFree)
         CMessageBox("Error", "Username is already taken.");
      else
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want to connect to your own ip from behind your own router you would have to use an external DNS for your network connection, also make sure that your firewall isn't blocking port 3306.

Comment: @Silvermind Umm, I might not of worded what i'm trying to do correctly, my apologies if I didn't. What I want is for my application to be able to connect to my MySQL database when the application is running off of some random person's machine in their network.

Comment: Easiest way is to just use your machine name if it is inside the LAN or a VPN. Otherwise you have probably not setup your firewall correctly or mysql.

Comment: @Silvermind I feel bad now, I have no idea what you're talking about :( I think I know my machine name but I have no idea what an LAN or VPN are. To be honest, I thought I was just missing a few letters or didn't have something open. I thought you could just use your public IP to connect to a mysql database hosted on that IP.

Comment: i think this is very off-topic. It is a really specific situation, where everything is unknown. We dont now about how the network is build, how are the public and private ips, if the is a server or more, if the router os bloking any port, if it is redirecting them to the correct machines, if the mysql server is listening to the standar public port (3306) or not, and a bunch of other things. Its a full tutorial what you are asking for!

Comment: @CarlosRobles All I'm asking is what to replace `localhost` with to make it so users from all networks can connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

try to get your IP.

open a command line (Start button > search... > cmd)

and run

```
ipconfig /all
```

Look for IPv4 Address. thats your local ip.

Try using that as your host. If its working, you are almost done. only have to configure yourself as an fixed ip in your network.

If its not working, you will have to chek a lot of things as i commented in your question, and that will be hard to answer here.

good luck!

Comment: From what i've read, my IPv4 is only know to my router (local). I'm wanting to know what to do to make it so some random person who downloads my application won't be denied access when they try to connect to the mysql database. Really just wanting to know what to use instead of `localhost` for the datasource.

Comment: so, its what i said in my comment. you need a static public ip from your ISP, a router than support access from outside, open some ports, redirect them to a local machine, configure that machine in the network to use always the same private ip and listen to that ports, and then configure the local sql server to serve request from outside.